# How to Displaying large number of records in Visualforce page block

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, pagination

I what to display 3000 records in a Visualforce page, is it possible?

Any help is posted.

Comment: mind clarifying why ?

Comment: It would be beneficial for the entire community if you were more specific in your question. What type of issue are you running into that is causing a problem? Do you have specific code that isn't working? Are you just trying to find out what the limitations are? We need some more info to be able to answer properly, otherwise this will be closed as this is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: also, from a usability perspective, displaying 3000 records on one page is not a best practice at all. I can hardly imagine that you would realy display all 3000 of them at the same time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to accomplish this you would need to use pagination to control the view state.  You would have a few options.

You could use `OFFSET` in your controller to manually control the records being sent to the VF page.  The issue with this method is the maximum OFFSET that you can use is 2,000.  If your use case is 3,000, then you will need another alternative.

Heres some documentation around `OFFSET`

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm

You could use the StandardSetController.  The limit for the StandardSetController is 10,000.  This might work for your use case.  According to documentation...

> StandardSetController objects allow you to create list controllers
>   similar to, or as extensions of, the pre-built Visualforce list
>   controllers provided by Salesforce.

I have used StandardSetControllers in the past for pagination.  The class has instance methods specifically for pagination.  You can set the page size (number of records to show at once), and Next and Previous pages without having to manually re-query any data.

Theres a very good blog post on how to implement pagination using StandardSetController.

http://hisrinu.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/pagination-using-standardsetcontroller/

> **EDIT**

to @Sdry 's point, you still would likely want some sort of filtering option as well, to try to limit the number of records.  Generally speaking, giving an end user access to large quantities of data in the UI, with no way to find what they actually want, is counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible .. maybe. Is someone telling you do to it this way .. maybe.  Do you really want to do that .. **No.**

Who is going to read 3000 records on a page ? The best practise advise is to implement filtering and pagination. People do not want to look at 3000 records, they want to draw certain conclusions or view details.

If on the other hand you're trying to put so many records on the page to perform some sort of export, there are much better techniques for this, which may depent on the true goal you're trying to achieve.